# Creating empty file in all subfolders

Tags: bash

I need to extract an archive and create a empty file in each of the folders contained within the archive.

I tried this:

```
for folder in `ls -d1 */` ; do touch "${folder}/COMPLETE"; done;
```

works just perfect till someone creates a folder with a space in its name.

How can I do this for all folders with or without spaces in their names?

\Hugo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use find instead:

```
find . -type d -exec touch {}/COMPLETE \;
```

Comment: replaced . with * as I don't need a COMPLETE file in main directory.
Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 6):

don't parse `ls` with `for` loop

```
for folder in */
do
  touch "$folder/COMPLETE"
done
```