# Creating empty file in all subfolders with unique name - bash

Tags: linux, bash

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935764/creating-empty-file-in-all-subfolders)

but I want to have file name be the same name as the directory with "_info.txt" appended to it.

I have tried this

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read line; do
    touch /Users/xxx/git/xxx/$line/$line_info.txt
done
```

It is creating ".txt" in each subdirectory.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Your spec is unclear ... do you want the *_info text to be "$folder_info.txt", or just the name of the subdirectory described by *?

Comment: i want the  *_info text to be "$folder_info.txt" under the directory $folder.

Comment: So what was the purpose of the extra "/*/" between $folder and _info.txt?

Comment: modified using the find command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read line; do
touch /Users/xxxx/git/xxxx/$line/"$line"_info.txt
done
```

I think I can still do the "find ."  better as I have to run in directory I want the files added to. Ideally it should be able to be run anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial mistake is that the underscore character is a valid character for a bash variable name:

```
$ a=1
$ a_b=2
$ echo $a_b
2
```

There are several ways around this:

```
$ echo "$a"_b
1_b
$ echo $a'_b'
1_b
$ echo ${a}_b
1_b
```

As for your task, here's a fast way:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%p_info.txt\0" | xargs -0 touch
```

The `find -printf` prints the path of each directory, and `printf`'s `%p` is unaffected by an underscore after it. Then, `xargs` passes the filenames as many arguments to few runs of `touch`, making the creation of the files much faster.

Comment: From the link i guess the info.txt file should be inside the directory and not at the same level.

Comment: @sjsam, i modified my answer; i'm not sure if your comment is relevant now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -type d | while read line
do
touch "$line/$(basename $( readlink -m $line))_info.txt"
done
```

Save it as, say, `appendinfo` and run it as

```
./appendinfo directory_name_which_include_symlinks
```

**Before**

```
ssam@udistro:~/Documents/so$ tree 36973628
36973628
`-- 36973628p1
    `-- 36973628p2
        `-- 36973628p3

3 directories, 0 files
```

**After**

```
ssam@udistro:~/Documents/so$ tree 36973628
36973628
|-- 36973628_info.txt
`-- 36973628p1
    |-- 36973628p1_info.txt
    `-- 36973628p2
        |-- 36973628p2_info.txt
        `-- 36973628p3
            `-- 36973628p3_info.txt

3 directories, 4 files
```

**Note :** readlink canonicalizes the path by following the symlinks. It is not required if, say, you're not going to give arguments like `.`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not recursing at all, you don't need `find`. To loop over subdirectories, all you need is

```
for dir in */; do
    touch /Users/xxxx/git/xxxx/"$dir/${dir%/}_info.txt"
done
```

Incidentally, notice that the variable needs to be in double quotes always.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
find . /Users/xxx/git/xxx/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'touch ${0}/${0##*/}_info.txt' {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the path to the folder.  I think you meant to write

```
touch "./$folder/*/*_info.txt"
```

Although this still only works if you start in the right directory.  You should really have written something like

```
touch "/foo/bar/user/$folder/*/*_info.txt"
```

However, your use of "*/*_info.txt" is very... questionable... to say the least.  I'm no bash expert, but I don't expect it to work.  Reading everything in a directory (using "find" for example, and only accepting directories) and piping that output to "touch" would be a better approach.

Comment: your are right Eric, find is better. Let me look at that. Absolute path did not work, btw.