# protobuf and python: can protoc generate __init__.py files?

Tags: python, python-import, python-2.x, python-module, protobuf-python

Is there a way to ask protoc to generate empty `__init__.py` files in the directories that it uses to generated the .py files so that they can be used as modules?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue. I'm surprised this was not solved yet by protoc. Also it seems the protoc generated Python code has other issues. See https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/881

So the answer is at the moment **no**. Protoc cannot generate `__init__.py` files.

One option may be to use https://github.com/danielgtaylor/python-betterproto to generate Python code from .proto (our proto definitions are also structured in subfolders).

The other option I'm currently looking into is to add an empty **init**.py file manually with a bash script: [Creating empty file in all subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935764/creating-empty-file-in-all-subfolders)

```
find <path-to-generated-python-proto> -type d -exec touch {}/__init__.py \;
```

Edit: I entered the empty `__init__.py` to all folders of generated code and then I can package Python modules using `find_packages` (as that only finds modules with `__init__.py`).